# Order Status Background Color according to the order status laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I was working on a laravel project with total order management system And I want to get the status background color according to the status of the order.

This is part of my code i have tried but it didn't work

```
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ order['id'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order['date'] }}</td>
                        <td class="width-40">{{ order['link'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order['charge'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ order['quantity'] }}</td>
                      <td>
                        {% if order['status'] == Completed %}
                          <span class="label label-success">Accepted</span>
                        {% elseif order['status'] == Canceled %}
                          <span class="label label-danger">Deleted</span>
                        {% else %}
                          <span class="label label-warning">Pending</span>
                        {% endif %}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

It didn't work on my project every time it just shows the pending one and yes i have 6 status

```
    Pending, In progress, Completed, Partial, Processing, Canceled
```

according to this the order status span should change i can't do it if anyone could give me a hand that would be a great help for me.

Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to SO .. which framework is this.? it not looking blade template

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
   {% if order['status'] == Completed %}
      <span class="label label-success">Accepted</span>
   {% elseif order['status'] == Cancelled %}
      <span class="label label-danger">Deleted</span>
   {% else %}
      <span class="label label-warning">Pending</span>
   {% endif %}
</td>
```

refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_labels2&stacked=h

Comment: Thankyou! For your participation in helping me. But I don't have any problem in classes or in the span i think its due to the json and script.